# Regular Expression to return the contents of a HTML tag received as a string of text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in my code that I receive that contains some html tags. It is not part of the HTML page being displayed so I cannot grab the html tag contents using the DOM (i.e. `document.getElementById('tag id').firstChild.data);`

So, for example within the string of text would appear a tag like this:

```
 <span id='myQty'>12</span>
```

My question is how would I use a regular expression to access the '12' numeric digit in this example? This quantity could be any number of digits (i.e. it is not always a double digit).

I have tried some regular expressions, but always end up getting the full span tag returned along with the contents. I only want the '12' in the example above, not the surrounding `<span>` tag. The id of the `<span>` tags will always be 'myQty' in the string of text I receive.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Don't. Just don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @David Dorward Too late, daemons have awakened... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var testfunction = function (input) {
    var regvar = new RegExp(/^(<span id\='myQty'>\w+<\/span>)$/);
    if (regvar.test(input) === true) {
        input = input.slice(6, input.length - 7);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just trying to get a specific value from inside a specific tag structure, and not trying to use regular expressions to strip HTML tags:

```
var myQtyMatch = str.match(/<span id='myQty'>(\d+)<\/span>/);
if (myQtyMatch) {
    var myQty = myQtyMatch[1];
    // myQty now holds the value between the <span> tags.
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick help... I actually implemented Jon's logic. Worked great!